# CSS - target last instance of div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div structure as below and i want to only target the last .pcontain on the page so i can remove the border-right - how do i go about it?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="postcontainer">
        <div class="latest-posts">
            <div class="thumbnail"></div>
            <div class="pcontain"></div>
            <div class="more"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postcontainer">
        <div class="latest-posts">
            <div class="thumbnail"></div>
            <div class="pcontain"></div>
            <div class="more"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postcontainer">
        <div class="latest-posts">
            <div class="thumbnail"></div>
            <div class="pcontain"></div>
            <div class="more"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postcontainer">
        <div class="latest-posts">
            <div class="thumbnail"></div>
            <div class="pcontain"></div>
            <div class="more"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55gFC/9/)

Use `last child`

```
.postcontainer:last-child .pcontain{ 
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

[Read more about last-child here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: Please don't link to [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) use http://w3.org instead if you care about spreading *accurate* information ..

Comment: @Adrift So what's inaccurate about that page?

Comment: @Adrift I didn't think you did. Also, I will change the link

Comment: I'm not too sure how this would be used specifically for my div structure as above. Any chance you could explain it's usage, particular to my case please? Btw, i didn't downvote FWIW.

Comment: @NikkiMather I will create a fiddle for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`last-child`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alast-child) pseudo-class like:

```
.postcontainer:last-child .pcontain {
color: darkolive;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZMZn/10/

Comment: I don't think you even need the '.container' in there.